# In radio button control how to achieve Text before radio circle?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

What I have

[image]

I want to achieve something like this:

[image]

This is the reference link that I have used to create radio button existing control: https://github.com/kirtisagar/XamarinFormsRadioButtonXAML

.Xaml Page:

```
<radio:BindableRadioGroup
                Spacing="10"
                x:Name="DeviceConditionRadio"
                ItemsSource="{Binding DeviceConditionList}"/>
```

.CS page:

here I have added Item source of radio:

`DeviceConditionList is a List<string>()`

```
 DeviceConditionList.Add("This device works well");
 DeviceConditionList.Add("This device is not working properly");
```

How to get this kind of design?
Any help regarding this appreciated.!
Thanks.

Comment: How did u code it? You have to provide us ur code

Comment: Can you provide the code you used for what you have, please? We can them possibly help you with what you need.

Comment: @Csharpest this is what I have referred to create radio button:
https://github.com/kirtisagar/XamarinFormsRadioButtonXAML/tree/master/XFormsRadioButton/XFormsRadioButton/CustomControls

Comment: @Tom please find the reference link from my previous comment.

Comment: @MShah Ok, but what have **you** written? How did you code your "What I have" section?

Comment: use a label and button combination for this and create a control for that!!

Comment: @Tom please find my edited post.

Comment: @G.hakim This would be one of the approach I can use but by using this solution I need to manage all radio button events manually, this would be quite time consuming.
So it would be great if I can use radio button itself instead of design with Label and circle.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: iOS does not have radio button anyway how do you plan on working with that then? You anyway have to create a custom class for that rather i say you do it for forms

Answer (score 1):

from the shared link, the default style is `Title` right and `Image` left.And the project is based on Custom renderer to do that. You can find the renderer here.
[image]
so you can modify this style by renderer.In the shared project not custom `RadioButton` 
in Android and `Button` in IOS.Then you need custom in each of them.

**Android** :you can modify `xml` to exchange the title and image of `RadioButton` like this:

```
  <RadioButton
     android:id="@+id/button1"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:button="@null"//set null
     android:checked="true"
     android:drawableRight="@android:drawable/btn_radio"//reset the image
     android:paddingLeft="10dp"
     android:text="RadioButton" />
```

`android:button="@null"`:This statement hides the original system's RadioButton icon.
`android:drawableRight="@android:drawable/btn_radio"`:Add a btn_radio icon that comes with the system to the right of the original icon. I think the RadioButton is packaged on the btn_radio icon.

**IOS**:Just extend Uibutton to custom button,and modify like this:

```
CGFloat imageWidth = jumpBtn.imageView.bounds.size.width;
CGFloat labelWidth = jumpBtn.titleLabel.bounds.size.width;
jumpBtn.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, labelWidth, 0, -labelWidth);
jumpBtn.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, -imageWidth, 0, imageWidth);
```

The titleEdgeInsets property and the imageEdgeInsets property are only used to adjust the image and label position properties when the button is drawn, and do not affect the size of the button itself.

If the image is to the right and the label is to the left, the left side of the image is shifted to the right of the labelWidth from the left side of the button, and the right side of the image is moved to the right by the labelWidth from the left side of the label.

Comment: Thanks for the help, will try this one and let you know.